# Cannot import pygtk in pythonbrew after manual install

Tags: python, pygtk, pythonbrew

Since it is impossible to install pygtk via `pip` I tried to install it manually.

I downloaded the source tar from [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyGTK/2.24.0) and ran

```
./configure --prefix=/home/user/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2
make
make install
```

It installed alright, e.g. `pygtk-demo` is in my path. However whenever I try to `import pygtk` I get the following error:

```
>>> import pygtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygtk
```

I seem to miss something or made an error. What do I have to do to be able to use pygtk?

Comment: If you downvote the question after three years, at least a comment would be nice. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not use pip or pythonbrew, but here is my experience, hope it can help and maybe put you on the good path !

The best option is to use the repository.
Under ubuntu, this goes with synaptic or apt-get.

When manually must be choosen, remember the pygtk is just a bridge to the gtk package, and this one must be installed first.
Usually, it happens this way :

- download gtk.zip, and unzip in a folder, say "gtk".
- add that folder "gtk" to your path

that's it, gtk is installed. 
now you can fasten it up with the blas/lapack math libs. 
You need a fortran compiler to do this.

Then after, you may think of pygtk.

But this one needs other py-things in order to run correctly, and they must also been installed first :

- pyGobject   : lets you communicate with gtk objects
- pyCairo  : handles the pretty fonts in the graphs, tables, ...

For all those py-something packages, the to-do way is always :

- download, then unzip in a temporary folder
- go to that temporary folder
- python setyp.py make
- python setup.py install

I did this several times on ubuntu  8, 9, 10 and 11, with success, when versions of all the packages where compatible between each other, which was not always easy....

If you can find "bundles" with all in it for your platform, give them your preference.

Then, the first thing to do is to test in python :

```
import gtk
import pygtk
```

Good luck !

Comment: Maybe I *should* go with the platform provided Python. Ever since I used `perlbrew` I fell in love with the concept of having your own interpreter in `~`. It provides so much flexibility and also saves a lot of headaches when a module is not available in the repository of whatever distribution one is using.

Comment: Oh, apart from that: `python setup.py make` etc. is only available on Windows (I'm on Linux). This seems to be the reason `pip` can't install the library as it relies on `setup.py`.

Comment: Ok, I did a little more research. It seems my main problem is that the Python module `pygtk` is not provided by the pygtk tar but by the pygobject tar. I find this very confusing. Be that as it may, I think this should solve my problem. Currently I'm not able to build `pygobject` due to compiler errors but this is another question.

Comment: I use the python setup.py make install ... on ubuntu (and used it on windows too, years ago). Now all other pysomething need to be setup.py in their temporary install folder. Good luck anyway. I'll try to help further if I can, just let me know !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment variable PYTHONPATH.  Thus, Python will know where
to look at.

Try:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python/...
```

where 'lib/python/...' is the real path to the module pygtk.

You might want to add that line in your ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile (or
the one that applies to the shell you use).

Comment: Ok. My main issue with this is: Why don't I have to do it with all the other modules I install with `pip`? They are installed into `.../Python-2.7.2/` as well.

Comment: Probably because the /python-2.7.2/libs is on your path and the pygtk path just differs a little bit. Best is to     export PYTHONPATH="~/python-2.7.2/pygtk"     in  /etc/profile (machine-wide)